# find list of files not modified for last 30 days in clearcase

Tags: find, clearcase

I need to find list of files which are not modified for last 30 days. This means there should be no version of the file under any branch in last 30 days. is this possible in base clearcase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try first, from the [query_language](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/query_language.htm) and [`cleartool find`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm), the syntax

```
cleartool find <vobtag> -element "!{created_since(target-data-time)}" -print
```

---

If that does not work, you would then have to fallback to:

- list all files with a version created in the last 30 days
- list all files and extract the ones which are not part of the first list.

Regarding said first list (from "[How to determine the last time a VOB was modified](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21257286)"), using [`cleartool find`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm):

```
cleartool find <vobtag> -element "{created_since(target-data-time)}" -print
or
cleartool find <vobtag> -version "{created_since(target-data-time)}" -print
```

That document also mentions `cleartool lshistory -minor -all .`, but that unreliable as it uses local metadata that can be scrapped at any time.

For the second list:

```
cleartool find . -cview -ele -print
```

Comment: I have tried the first option.But, as there are thousands of files,i am not 100% sure about it if its correct.

Comment: @user2636464 just pick one and see its version tree, to see if there are versions created sonce those last 30 days

Comment: The cleartool find command at the top will work on the element creation date, and not the version timestamps... I think there is a way, let me see if I can create something. I believe that you can use the find -version "created_since..." to give you a list of elements with modifications, and then diff it against a list of all elements in the VOB.

Comment: @BrianCowan I suspected as much. And using version wouldn't do any good, as it would list all versions created before a certain date, while there could still be versions created *after*.

Comment: " I believe that you can use the find -version "created_since..." ": that is what I propose in the second part of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample Perl script to do what you're asking for. This has a hard-coded date string to avoid getting bogged down in Perl date arithmetic. It takes the list of all elements in the VOB, and then deletes elements with versions modified since the date specified from that list, finally outputting the non-modified elements.

```
#!/usr/bin/Perl -w
my %elem_hash;
my $datestring="01-jan-2014";
my $demarq=    "-------------------------------------------------";
my $allelemtxt="--   All elements located in the current VOB   --";
my $ver_hdr   ="--     Versions modified since $datestring     --";
my $nonmodtext="--   Elements not modified since $datestring   --";
#
# Get all elements in the current VOB.
#
$cmdout=`cleartool find -all -print`;
@elemtext=split('\n',$cmdout);
#
# Add them to a hashmap, simply because it's easier to delete from this list type
#
foreach $elem (@elemtext)
{
    # Quick and dirty way to remove the @@ 
    $elem = substr($elem,0,length($elem)-2);
    $elem_hash{$elem} = 1;
}
#
printf("\n%s\n%s\n%s\n",$demarq,$allelemtxt,$demarq);
foreach $elem2 (sort (keys (%elem_hash)))
{
    printf("Element: %s\n",$elem2);
}

#
# Get VERSIONS modified since the specified date string
#

$cmdout=`cleartool find -all -version "created_since($datestring)" -print`;
@vertext=split('\n',$cmdout);

#
# strip the trailing version id's and then delete the resulting key from the hashmap.
#
printf("\n%s\n%s\n%s\n",$demarq,$ver_hdr,$demarq);
foreach $version (@vertext)
{
    printf("Version: %s\n",$version);
    $version=substr($version,0,length($version)-(length($version)- rindex($version,"@@")));
    if (exists($elem_hash{$version}))
    {
        delete $elem_hash{$version};
    }
}

printf("\n%s\n%s\n%s\n",$demarq,$nonmodtext,$demarq);
foreach $elem2 (sort (keys (%elem_hash)))
{
    printf("Element: %s\n",$elem2);
}
```